# Chrome memory measurement now almost flat for longer test runs

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

In order to check our web application for memory leaks, I run a machine which does the following:

- it runs automated End-to-End tests over (almost) the entire application in Chrome
- after each block of tests, it goes to a state of the web application where almost nothing happens
- it triggers `gc();` for garbage collection
- it saves `totalJSHeapSize`, and `usedJSHeapSize` to a file
- it plots out the results for each test run to a graph

That way, we can see how much the memory increases and which are the problematic parts of our application: At some point the memory increases, at some point it decreases.
Till yesterday, it looked like this:

[image]
Bright red (upper line): totalJSHeapSize, light red (lower line): usedJSHeapSize

Yesterday, I updated Chrome to version 69. And now the chart looks quite different:

[image]
The start and end amount of memory used (usedJSHeapSize) is almost the same. But as you can clearly see, the way it changes over the course of the test (ca. 1,5h) is quite different.

My questions are now:

- Is this a change in reality or in measurement? I.e. did Chrome change its memory handling? Or just the way it puts out memory values via `totalJSHeapSize`, and `usedJSHeapSize`?
- Concerning memory leaks, is it good news or bad news for me? Like: Before I had dozens of spots where memory increases, now I have just three. Is this true? Or are the memory leaks in the now flat areas still there and hidden?

I'm also thankful for any background information on how Chrome changed its memory measurement.

Some additional info:

- The VM runs under KUbuntu 18.04
- It's a single web page application done with AngularJS 1.6
- The outcome of the memory measurement is quite stable - both before and after the update of Chrome

**EDIT:**
It seems this was a bug of Chrome version 69. At least, with an **update to Chrome 70**, this strange behavior is gone and everything looks almost as before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be worry about it. This can happen due to the memory manager used inside the chrome. You didn't mentioned the version of your first memory graph, possibility that the memory manager used between these two version is different. Chrome was using the TCMalloc which take the large chunk of memory from the OS and manage it, once the memory shortage happenned with TCMalloc then it ask again a big chunk of memory from OS and start managing it. So the later graph what you are seeing have less up and downs (but bigger then previous one) due to that. Hope it answered your query.

As you mentioned that

> The outcome of the memory measurement is quite stable - both before and after the update of Chrome

You don't need to really worry about it, the way previously chrome was allocating memory and how it does with new version is different(possible different memory manager) that's it.

Comment: Well, my question is not so much about how Chrome manages its memory during heavy load or when many things going on, but about how the memory is kept afterward and how this is measured. As I said, my measurement happens AFTER a test block when a state of "nothing to do" is reached. So what confuses me: If beforehand, there was a memory leak between point 1 and point 2 and now there is none anymore there - why is the amount of memory added at the end almost the same?

Comment: @cis "why is the amount of memory added at the end almost the same?" As mentioned this is due to memory manager used by chrome in later version. Memory manager take a fixed amount of memory from the OS and manage it internally. Thats why you are seeing the same amount of memory up in the second graph.

Comment: In my understanding, what you are describing and what TCMalloc does is about memory negotiations between Chrome and the OS. However, I had always assumed that Chrome's handling of one single website's memory consumption is not directly affected by that. I'm not measuring the amount of memory Chrome consumes at all. I'm measuring the amount of memory Chrome states to have allocated for my application.

Comment: @cis "I'm measuring the amount of memory Chrome states to have allocated for my application." what is that mean? Your application is an web application, right? which runs in the chrome? Hope you are aware about the chrome process architecture like browser process, renderer process. There will be a one browser process for one instance of chrome browser and one renderer process per tab ( it depends on the domain you are opening).

Comment: Well, I mean: I don't care about how Chrome organizes its processes. I'm using what Chrome returns me via (as stated above) the properties `totalJSHeapSize`, and `usedJSHeapSize` which are part of Chrome's `window.performance.memory` object. Basically, with these values, Chrome is telling me `I'm using N bytes of memory for your web app right now." -- I don't care how Chrome obtains that amount of memory from the OS, in which process it is stored and so on. Or should I care?

Comment: @cis I mentioned the same in my answer that you don't need to bother about it.

Comment: usedJsHeapSize is the total amount of memory being used by JS objects including V8 internal objects, totalJsHeapSize is current size of the JS heap including free space not occupied by any JS objects. This means that usedJsHeapSize can not be greater than totalJsHeapSize. Note that it is not necessarily that there has ever been totalJsHeapSize of alive JS objects.

Comment: Well, I don't care about Chrome's internals. But I do care about memory leaks in my app. And I still don't see an explanation of the changed memory values. Before the update, it was like: Small problem at 1, small problem at 2, medium problem at 3. Now it is: No problem at 1, no problem at 2, big problem at 3. So, either Chrome has changed its JavaScript memory handling with many optimizations and regressions - which by coincidence end at almost the same values as the before. Seems unlikely. Or Chrome changed the way it exposes its memory values. Rendering them maybe useless to me.

Comment: what is making you to think that there is a memory leak? Your totalJsHeapSize will always be greater then usedJSHeapSize. Tell me how you come to the conclusion that there is a memory leak?

Comment: Because both `totalJSHeapSize`, and `usedJSHeapSize` grow over time (or to be more precise: after some test blocks). After all tests have finished, `usedJSHeapSize` is ca. 70-80 MB higher than at the starting point. I've already found and solved some memory leaks in my app by looking at the chart and identifying problematic spots.

Comment: @cis have a look on the link which definitely help you  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: I know that article. As I said, I already solved quite a few memory leaks. That whole topic is not new to me. What is new, is the changed behavior of Chrome's memory value output. That is nowhere mentioned in the linked article.

Comment: See my edit: An update to Chrome 70 turned back the previous behavior.